# Date filtering in Excel Online

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I might be completely overlooking the feature, but i've been trying to filter a range of dates to only display today and future days in Excel Online (365).

At first sight it appears that there is such a feature:

> Data > Filter > Click array on column > Date Filters > ...

However, there is no default filter to display only today and future dates. There is one to do the exact opposite (Year To Day). So I guess it would be either `custom filter`.

In the next screen I can't seem to add a `TODAY()` function or anything at all. So definitely no `TODAY()-1` or something.

Any suggestions anyone or is this just a feature that hasn't made it to Excel online..

Example sheet: https://protimeeu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/donald_valkaert_protime_eu/EVCQvYZ-4i9HvMHGHS-cwJcBKun_D6NzHuEWSgbNxbLiMg?e=m3Ams1

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot about your problem? I checked my Excel online and my Data Filter as shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D1oS.png

Comment: @Lee i've added an example of the sheet i've been using. Since both you and Clare seem to indicate that it should work, i'm guessing it's going to be a syntax error of problem of another sort.

Comment: Then maybe I have the condition wrong I put in the input field, what should I put in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dates in a table in Excel Online in same way as normal via Date Filters.

Apply a custom filter that uses the condition 'Is after or equal to' then the value of 'Today'

Comment: I can't seem to get this working using this example sheet: https://protimeeu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/donald_valkaert_protime_eu/EVCQvYZ-4i9HvMHGHS-cwJcBKun_D6NzHuEWSgbNxbLiMg?e=m3Ams1

Comment: It looks like the issue is you've not formatted your data into a table. Try having a look at this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-online-service-description/excel-online) Once you've converted the range into a table you should be able to see the custom filter menu.

Comment: I see the custom filter menu, I just cannot do the dynamic filter that is described. As seen in @fixer1234 his post :-(

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it turns out it isn't obvious, and doesn't work quite the way we were all guessing.  Here's how you can set the filter to "today and future dates".

Use the Filter pull-down (the little icon already showing in the "Date" column heading), and select `After`.

[image]
*<sup>Thanks, Lee, for the image.</sup>*

That will open a little dialog window prefilled with `is greater than` and an entry box.

Type yesterday's date in that box, and click OK.

[image]

Unfortunately, you can't insert functions like TODAY() or cell references, you can't use multiple selections from the initial list, like `After` and `Yesterday`, and picking one of the date offerings from the list automatically assigns `=` as the comparison.

Comment: That seems to coincide with my findings. I was hoping I was just not seeing the solution.

Comment: @Donaldini, Excel Online has many crippled features.  It's fine for basic stuff, but it doesn't replicate everything in the installable (and paid) version of the software.  It's kind of surprising that it offers as much as it does in a free web app.